# Java command not going to background with &

Tags: unix, java, aix, unix-shell

I'm running a java command:

```
java weblogic.Admin -adminurl t3://URL:POST -username username -password password START $SERVER &
```

on an Aix machine.

The problem is that the shell still halts until the command is completed. What should I do to make it return back to the terminal immediately.

Comment: could you post the whole command line?

Comment: What happens if you press `ctrl-z` then?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add "nohup" to the beginning.  SO, it would be something like:

```
nohup java weblogic.Admin -adminurl t3://URL:POST -username username 
-password password START $SERVER & echo $! > pid.txt
```